# Create User with Endpoint - Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, endpoint

User must be created from an API endpoint it has only one attribute `:nick`

I sent the Post request with PostMan but I have a routing error

Here are my routes:

```
  resources :users
```

In Users Controller I have  `new` and `create`action, like so:

```
    def new 
        @user = User.new
    end 

    def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save!
      head :created
    else
      head :no_content
    end
  end
```

In Postman :
I have selected **Post** and the url is `http://localhost:3000/users/new`

In Header I have:

```
Key                Value
Content-Type       Application/Json
```

Here is the body:

```
{   
    "data": {
        "type": "user",
        "attributes": {
        "nick": "Liwis"
        }
    }
 }
```

When I send the request it returns that:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/new"):

actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:682:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Wrong url. You create resources by posting to `http://localhost:3000/users`. The new action just renders a form.

Comment: Yes I finally found out  thanks anyway